# Gherking/cucumber table alternative syntax

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I'm wondering if it is possible to configure Gherkin/cucumber parser to support not just the default table syntax like:

```
| title | value |
| foo   | 10    |
```

but alternative styles as well like the two below:

```
| title | value |
|-------+-------|
| foo   |    10 |
| bar   |    20 |
```

or:

```
| title | value |
|-------+-------|
| foo   |    10 |
|-------+-------|
| bar   |    20 |
|-------+-------|
```

My steps implementation language is Ruby